# XSL select value of an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

So I probably didn't word the title well. But, what I want to do is given the following xml excerpt:

```
<id name="tim" number="5555665" />
```

I would like to pull out the actual name and number of id. I have tried:

```
<xsl:value-of select="id.name"/>
AND
<xsl:value-of select="id/name"/>
```

Neither of which have done the trick. How can I access these data values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="id/@name"/>

<xsl:value-of select="id/@number"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

To select attribute values with XPath, [use the `@` selector](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp):

```
<xsl:value-of select="id/@name" />
<xsl:value-of select="id/@number" />
```